# Is there a trick to show Google Chart Animation when vAxis.logScale is true?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to use `vAxis {logScale : true ,...}` in the options of a `AreaChart` of *Google chart* package but **when i add** **`logScale : true`** to its options, It causes a problem in the animation scan.

**When i remove** it, the animation works nice.

Is there any way to show animation **on startup** by a Google chart when `vAxis.logScale` is `true`?

**Demo**

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2013',  1000,      400],
          ['2014',  1170,      460],
          ['2015',  660,       1120],
          ['2016',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            logScale:true  // << It cause animation problem
          },          
          animation:{
          startup:true,
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'out',
          },

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41514946/5090771) when using `animation.startup`
this appears to be another...

to get animation to work with `logScale`,
remove `animation.startup`

use a blank data table to draw the chart initially

and a **one time** `'ready'` event listener,
to immediately draw the chart again with the correct data...

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['', 0, 0],
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        logScale: true
      },
      animation:{
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      data.removeRow(0);
      data.addRows([
        ['2013', 1000, 400],
        ['2014', 1170, 460],
        ['2015', 660, 1120],
        ['2016', 1030, 540]
      ]);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);

    $(window).resize(function() {
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i made another solution for it and wrote it in this page as an answer. Both of them try to recall `chart.draw(...)` to fix startup animation problem. I mark your answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made a fix for this *bug* myself.

Using it is **so simple**. Just add the following **fix function** to your script and **call it before first `chart.draw(...)`**.

**The fix function:**

```
function fixLogScaleAnimation(chart,data, opts){
    if(opts.vAxis.logScale){
        opts.vAxis.logScale=false;
        google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            opts.vAxis.logScale=true;
            chart.draw(data, opts);
        });
     }
 }
```

**Use:**

```
chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
fixLogScaleAnimation(chart,data, options); // << Call the fix function here
chart.draw(data, options);
```

**Demo:**

```js
function fixLogScaleAnimation(chart,data, opts){
    if(opts.vAxis.logScale){
        opts.vAxis.logScale=false;
        google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            opts.vAxis.logScale=true;
            chart.draw(data, opts);
        });
     }
 }

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2013',  1000,      400],
    ['2014',  1170,      460],
    ['2015',  660,       1120],
    ['2016',  1030,      540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      logScale:true  // << It cause animation problem
    },          
    animation:{
    startup:true,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'out',
    },

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  fixLogScaleAnimation(chart,data, options); 
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

> *I think my way is a better (simple and clean) solution to this problem and i made it before anyone write an answer for it here but i mark @WhiteHat's answer as accepted answer because his solution works well too and he wrote his answer here before me. ;)*

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem is changing the configuration option of your `vAxis` to:

```
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        0: {logScale: true}
      }
```

Making the first axis on the graph scaled as log.

Comment: animation only works here because this actually removes the `logScale`, option for `vAxis.0` doesn't exist -- it would be `vAxes.0` with an `e` -- using `vAxes.0` produces same result as OP...